# Having Apache pass JS files through PHP FPM

Tags: php, apache

I've got Apache setup to run PHP through FPM and I want to be able to get .js files passed through FPM as well as .php files.

On my dev box I can do this:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .js
```

But on my live box, which is locked down more I get this error in the browser:

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://blah/test.js' because its MIME type ('application/x-httpd-php') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I've tried adding a handler with:

```
AddHandler php-fastcgi .js
```

I've tried setting a handler with these and other variations:

```
<FilesMatch \.js$>
    SetHandler php7-fastcgi
    #SetHandler php7-fcgi
</FilesMatch>
```

But none of them works. What do I need to do?

Comment: Make your server deliver these resources with an appropriate `Content-Type` header.

Comment: That is what AddType does, but that doesn't work for this, setting it to JavaScript allows the browser to use the script, but PHP doesn't see it, setting it to anything else, the browser blocks it and PHP still doesn't see it.

Comment: _“That is what AddType does”_ - well clearly in this instance it isn’t, because `application/x-httpd-php` is _not_ an appropriate mime type for JavaScript resources. Either add the appropriate content-type header from within your PHP code, or try adding it from within the .htaccess using the `Header` directive.

Comment: The problem wasn't that the browser wasn't accepting it, it was that it wasn't getting passed through PHP in the first place. Regardless of the MIME type, PHP wasn't seeing the script.

Comment: _“The problem wasn't that the browser wasn't accepting it”_ - well that’s what the error message you quoted said at least …

Answer (score 0):

I found it, the handler I needed to add is:

```
SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
```

Still needs some touch-ups on the content type that is served with it, but at least my JavaScript file is now going through PHP and I can add my dynamic content.

You also need to edit this line in /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf to allow FPM to handle .js files, otherwise the requests will be rejected.

```
security.limit_extensions = .php .js
```

My current hack to fix the MIME type is to add this in the PHP part of the file, but I've got a feeling I can fix it through Apache, but as the main problem is solved, I'm going to worry about that later.

```
header ("content-type: text/javascript");
```